# array of strings not storing correctly

Tags: c, arrays, string, recursion, directory

I'm implementing the `ls -R` linux command in C and I'm having trouble with the recursion step.
So far I have

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>


void lsr(char *directory){
    DIR             *dir;
    dir = opendir(directory);
    int size = 0;
    struct dirent   *d;
    char *que[100];
    char buf[100];
    while((d = readdir(dir)) != NULL){
        struct stat     statbuff;
        if(strcmp(d->d_name,".")== 0 || strcmp(d->d_name,"..")==0){
            continue;
        }
        sprintf(buf, "%s/%s", directory, d->d_name);
        stat(buf,&statbuff);
        printf(" %s",d->d_name);
        printf("\n");
        if(S_ISDIR(statbuff.st_mode)){
            printf("%s Is a directory\n",buf);
            que[size] = buf;
            size++;
        }
    }    
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
        printf("dir: %s\n",que[i]);
    }
    printf("Are in the queue\n");

    //for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
      //  lsr(que[i]);
    //}
    closedir(dir);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char directory[200];
    if(argc ==1){
        strcpy(directory,".");
    }
    else{
        strcpy(directory,argv[1]);
    }
    lsr(directory);
    return 0;
}
```

What im going for is that the function finishes printing all the files in the directory before it recurses into the first directory it found. The only thing i could think of is to store them into a array and then make the call that way.
If anyone could point out why it is that when i loop through the array, its content is wrong or maybe even better, A more practical solution as to how to recurse into directories after the file's names have been printed I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: So your Q is how to do the recursive call, or how to make the files being listed first before directories? Implementing a queue as you did is not a good way to do recursive, specifically how do you know that it has only 100 entries?

Answer (score 0):

Here you store the address pointed by `buf` in que[size].

```
que[size] = buf;
```

In the next loop iteration,`stat(buf,&statbuff);` modifies the content pointed by buf and `que[size]`
So every slot of you array points to this same address and everytime you modifies this content, you modifies the full array.
I suggest to use `strcpy()` or to reallocate buf before the `stat()` call.

Comment: do you mean say something like 
strcpy(que[size],buf)
 I tried that and got a segmentation fault

Comment: You need to allocate `que[size]` to do that.